# nodejs Installation windows 7 64bit .solve this error

Tags: node.js, windows

How to solve the below problem. Nodejs installation error.
[image]

Comment: please response quick............

Comment: how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

This error may come from different reasons. Some of them is you have not full access to the folder: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\`

Change the permissions to full access to this folder or run installation with Administrator mode

Comment: great answer Van-Duyet Le but not yet working.......i also try this answer method